# Getting multiple data from database (or so)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get multiple bookings from my database for a hotel project
when i tried to get the bookings from my database i only recieved one booking it should display/select multiple bookings.

This is my php code:
(formulier.php)

```
    <?php
    $dt1 = $_POST['date1'];
    $dt2 = $_POST['date2'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM dt_tb WHERE dt BETWEEN '$dt1' AND '$dt2'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { include_once 'source.php';
        }
    echo "<br>formulier.php";
    echo "<br>check-in:&nbsp;&nbsp; $dt1 <br>check-out: $dt2";

    }

    else {
        die;
    }
    ?>
```

---

And this is my other php code: (source.php)

```
<?php
$dt1 = $_POST['date1'];
$dt2 = $_POST['date2'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM dt_tb WHERE dt BETWEEN '$dt1' AND '$dt2'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    }
    echo "source.php";
    echo "<br>check-in:&nbsp;&nbsp; $dt1 <br>check-out: $dt2";
}

else {
    die;
}
?>
```

---

this is my database: (dt_tb)

https://gyazo.com/966efdf144a8cd1a74fa04a8127cd8f4

---

This is what i receive: (Website)

https://gyazo.com/1384bdafb5055f5777a40e88baccdbdd

---

I know my code is messed up badly and tried to solve it for quite some time.

Comment: '*I know my code is messed up badly and tried to solve it for quite some time.*' - What have you tried?

Comment: `include_once` in while loop will executes only once. Why you query database multiple times with same query?

Comment: @Script47 I've asked my teachers they said the first code of mine was very wrong then i started redoing the booking system i believe that im close to getting it right.

Comment: @Justinas I know, my teacher told me that aswell and i thought that was wrong aswell do you have any idea what i can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need two files. You can join them to single loop.

```
<?php
$dt1 = !empty($_POST['date1']) ? $_POST['date1'] : null;
$dt2 = !empty($_POST['date2']) ? $_POST['date2'] : null;

if (!$dt1 || !$dt2) {
   throw new Exception("No dates passed!");
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM dt_tb WHERE dt BETWEEN '$dt1' AND '$dt2'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "check-in:&nbsp;&nbsp; {$row['dt']}<br/>";
        echo "check-out: {$row['dt2']}<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No bookings found between {$dt1} and {$dt2}";
    die();
}
?>
```

---

What was wrong:

1. `require_once` is called only for first iteration, no further calls was made. It's used mostly when including classes or some configs, that must be included only once in whole logic.
2. You try to echo your data outside loop inside `source.php`
3. You echo passed parameters to server, but not actual database record entries. Changed `$dt1` to `$row['dt']` and `$dt2` to `$row['dt2']`

Comment: Thanks bro!

The code worked perfectly just added 1 HTML include for the bookin under its pretty much done now!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You repeated the query in both files! Why?
As you typed, you don't need to include 2 lines! , you can add them directly:

```
$dt1 = $_POST['date1'];
$dt2 = $_POST['date2'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM dt_tb WHERE dt BETWEEN '$dt1' AND '$dt2'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
       echo "source.php";
       echo "<br>check-in:&nbsp;&nbsp; $dt1 <br>check-out: $dt2";
    }
echo "<br>formulier.php";
echo "<br>check-in:&nbsp;&nbsp; $dt1 <br>check-out: $dt2";

}

else {
    die;
}
```

Comment: thats wrong :).

Why?: It's coming as strings. not as bookings.

https://gyazo.com/27ce708e2d303ec9ad532903b76832bb

Thanks for your time though.